# Remote API for large data processing

Tags: rest, web-services, soap, rmi, java-ee-7

I have a javaSE8App, processing large amount of serialisable objects. I also have a javaEE7app(Wildfly, CDI, JSF2) built on the top of the javaSE8App.

javaEE7App uses different algorithms from javaSE8App and displays the results to the user.

I would like to remotely upload large data into javaEE7app or javaSE8App, process it, get the result back for further processing in the client.
I am evaluating different options: SOAP, REST, RMI ...

What would be the best solution for a remote access of javaEE7app or javaSE8App API for large data processing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: RMI is not suitable for this. You need a streaming API.

Comment: I've indeed looked at kafka. But I still don't see how it could help

Comment: one technique I've used is messaging (JMS). Client sends message to broker with location of large data payload. App picks up message and ingests the data from the location and sends message to the broker when processing complete. ActiveMQ/Camel